# Como tratar o cabecalho de acordo com o nivel de acesso?

Tags: php, html5

Tenho um sistema de login e possuo a variável de nível de acesso e algumas informações são restritas para determinados funcionarios . Queria saber como faço para de acordo com esse nível aparecer apenas determinados campos .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possível solução para sua dúvida é por exemplo criar 2 cabeçalhos, e dar um **echo** no cabeçalho a ser exibido por cada usuário de acordo com seu nível deixando um visível enquanto o outro não.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$cabecalhoUser = '<a>Texto 1</a> | <a>Texto 2</a> | <a>Texto 3</a>';
$cabecalhoAdm = $cabecalhoUser.' | <a>Área Administrativa</a>';


//Usuário = 1 & Administrador = 2
$Nivel = 1;

if($Nivel == 1)
    echo '<nav>'.$cabecalhoUser.'</nav>';
else
    echo '<nav>'.$cabecalhoAdm.'</nav>';

?>
```